# remove initial charachter from string in django template

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

I have a variable in django template who prints  **"Due 17 Dec, MATHS: math homework"** I want only **MATHS: math homework** , how could I do that in django template.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the initial character (per your question title),

```
{{ my_string|slice:':1' }}
```

But your example removes more than that

```
{{ my_string|slice:':12' }}
```

If the processing is more complex than that, do it in the view, or write your own custom template filter.

Django deliberately discourages significant processing in templates.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanx for your ans.
actually my variable gives **[UPCOMING HOMEWORK] Due 17 Dec, MATHS: math homework** but I want **[UPCOMING HOMEWORK] MATHS: math homework**, will you help me to do this. Thanx

Comment: Well, it will involve changing it in the view or writing your own template filter, but change your question to reflect what you're asking.

Comment: yes, initially I have other requirnment, but now requirnment has been changed. but Thanx for your ans.